# Outputting specific values from an two dimensional array

Tags: java

Problem with output from a two dimensional array, basically 8 rows and 5 columns, each row represents one athlete, the five colums represent the points they have gained in each task. I have to find out If an athlete went beyond 250 points in a single task. Firstly, I made an integer which counts the number of times the Array has been look at, If the number can be divided by 5 it means the next number is going to be the next row and thus a new athlete, next I created another loop to check all the previous numbers and if any of them goes beyond 250, I add one number to the total + break the cycle. The result I have been getting back is 0, or before I got nothing.

```
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++) 
            if(rezultati[i][j]>0) {
                skaits = skaits + 1;
            }
            else if(skaits % 5==0) {
                for (int a=0; a<5; a++) {
                    if(rezultati[i-a][j-a]>250) {
                        daudzums = daudzums + 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }   
    }
```

realised that the row index should be just i if(rezultati[i][j-a]>250), didnt fix the issue tho

Comment: "If the number can be divided by 5 it means the next number is going to be the next row and thus a new athlete". Looking at your code this statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with all variables declared and show input and expected output.

Comment: Why not just check if the value is over 250 in the inner for loop `if(rezultati[i][j]>250)` instead of counting values > 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an outer loop that will move to the next row/athlete for you.  Simply look at the current value and if it exceeds 250, increment your counter and move to the next athlete with `break`:

```
int daudzums = 0;
int[][] rezultati = new int[8][5];
// ... populate zezultati somehow ...
for (int i=0; i<rezultati.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<rezultati[i].length; j++) {
        if (rezultati[i][j]>250) {
          daduzums++;
          break; // move to next athlete
        }
    }   
}   
System.out.println("daudzums = " + daudzums);
```

After the loops, `daudzums` will tell you how many athletes had at least one task over 250.